# Tag merge: OWA + Outlook Web Access

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

[owa](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/owa) and [outlook-web-access](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/outlook-web-access) overlap a bit. Should we merge them?

Bumping this again, as I just encountered both a [owa](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/owa) and [outlook-web-access](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/outlook-web-access) wiki edit review with nearly identical content.  Do tag merges not retroactively merge tags? Or do tags and tag wikis persist post-tag-merge?

Question in question is here: [Exchange 2010 - EMC and OWA non-functional after unexpected server reboot](https://serverfault.com/questions/469662/exchange-2010-emc-and-owa-non-functional-after-unexpected-server-reboot)

Comment: Also I was unable to remove the [status-completed] tag when bumping this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, merge.

From the perspective of a Windows admin with a fair bit of mail experience, no one says `Outlook Web Access`, it's just `OWA`, therefore, I'm personally a proponent of merging everything **into** [owa](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/owa), but I'm not sure it matters much which way they're merged, so long as they're merged.